# Как изменить положение блока bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap

Добрый день у меня возникла проблема с блоками при адаптировании в bootstrap. Когда я использую class col-sm-6, то хотел бы что бы блоки шли в два ряда, у меня таких блоков 4 и у них разные размеры, первые два становятся нормально, но уже третий стает на место 4 блока, а 4 блок становится ниже [картинка](http://www.online-upload.com/partials/test_uploads/Bez%C2%A0tytu%C5%82u_15.02.17_18.24.07.png)
Вот код:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card-row clearfix">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 clearfix">
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-5.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-8.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-8.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 clearfix">
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-6.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-7.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-7.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mod-col-3">
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-7.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-5.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-8.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mod-col-4">
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-8.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                        <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-6.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card ">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/layer-7.png"></a>
                    <div class="card-about">
                        <a href="#"><h3>Animation films</h3></a>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"><span>Movies</span></i>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="social clearfix">
                        <ul class="rate">
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star active"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                            <li class="star"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Может кто то знает решение данной проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте вместо класса `.col-sm-6` классы `.col-sm-3`. Суть в том, чтобы в сумме все цифры в классах на блоках, которые должны быть на одной строке, равнялись 12.

То есть, 6+6=12, поэтому два блока на одной строке. А если вы хотите 4 блока разместить на одной строке, тогда замените на `.col-sm-3` (3+3+3+3=12).